# MySQL - How to use a correlated subquery inside a JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group, correlated-subquery

I have two tables, `Objects` and `Events`.

`Objects` is structured like:

```
ID | Password
-------------
0  | aaaa
1  | bbbb
```

Events is structured like:

```
Object | Date       | Type
--------------------------
0      | 2020-06-01 | 0
0      | 2020-06-02 | 1
```

What I want to achieve is: for each ID, get the last Type of event associated. In the example above, Object `0` would be associated to `1`, since `1` was the Type of the last event on `2020-06-02`. Also, whenever an Object doesn't have any Events, associate `1` to it.

I tried to order the events for each Object, so that I could then join my Object information using the query:

```
SELECT ID, IFNULL(e.Type, 1)
FROM objects o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT e.Object, e.Date, e.Type
    FROM events e
    WHERE e.Object = o.ID
    ORDER BY e.Date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS e ON e.Object = o.ID
```

It does not work since `o.ID` is unknown, but I really can't think of any other solutions. Therefore my question is: how can I use an attribute of the outside table inside a condition for the joined table?

Please let me know if anything is unclear, thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output for this sample data?

Comment: I just need ID and Type. That's why I used `SELECT ID, IFNULL(e.Type, 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` in `Events` to return only the last row by Date:

```
SELECT ID, IFNULL(e.Type, 1) Type
FROM Objects o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT e.Object, e.Type
    FROM Events e
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM Events
      WHERE Object = e.Object AND Date > e.Date 
    ) 
) AS e ON e.Object = o.ID
```

or:

```
SELECT 
  o.ID, 
  IFNULL((SELECT e.Type FROM Events e WHERE e.Object = o.ID ORDER BY e.Date DESC LIMIT 1), 1) Type
FROM Objects o
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fe46f7cdcf3642dd77ac0bdd79f403e0).
Results:

```
> ID | Type
> -: | ---:
>  0 |    1
>  1 |    1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, IFNULL(e.Type, 1)
FROM objects o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT e.Object, max(e.Date), e.Type
    FROM events e
    GROUP BY e.Date DESC
) AS e ON e.Object = o.ID
```

Comment: No, because this only return the latest event joined to its object information, whereas I need the latest event for each object.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Then you need to aggregate the rows in the sub query. Something like the amended answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT o.id, max(e.date) AS date, e.type
FROM objects o
INNER JOIN events e ON(o.id = e.object)
GROUP BY o.id, e.type
ORDER BY e.date DESC;
```

output

```
+------+------------+------+
| id   | date       | type |
+------+------------+------+
|    0 | 2020-06-02 |    1 |
|    0 | 2020-06-01 |    0 |
+------+------------+------+
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have version 8 or above you could use the row_number() function to work out the last row

```
select * from
(
select id,coalesce(type,1) type,coalesce(date,date(now())) as dt,
         row_number() over (partition by o.id order by coalesce(date,date(now())) desc) rn
from  objects o
left join events e on e.object = o.id
order by o.id,dt desc
) s
where rn = 1;
```